# IF ELSE STATEMENT span style PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi, I'm changing the color of the text in the table according to its value... if the value is "posted" then its color is blue if it's "cancel" it's red...

I have been able to achieve it using an if statement:

```
<td><span style="<?php if($value['posted'] == 'posted')echo 'color:blue'?>"><?php echo $value['posted']; ?></span></td>
```

When I add an ELSE IF for the cancel I figured out that it should look like this;

```
<td><span style="<?php 
if($value['posted'] == 'posted')
{
echo 'color:blue'
} 
else if($value['posted'] == 'cancel')
{
   echo 'color:red'
}
?>">
<?php echo $value['posted']; ?></span></td>
```

But it's SYNTAX ERROR UnEXPECTED }

I know it's just a simple else if statement but I can't get it right. Please help...

Comment: Missing semicolon `;`.

Comment: Using the same logic, you could set a CSS class instead of a style attribute.  Then changing the color (or any other style aspect) of your rows is a simple edit of a stylesheet.  This is most useful if you reuse the same styles on several pages.  You change your CSS class in once place and your whole site updates.

Comment: @str got it thenks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need semicolons after your `echo`:

```
if($value['posted'] == 'posted')
{
   echo 'color:blue';//<-- right here
} 
else if($value['posted'] == 'cancel')
{
   echo 'color:red';//<-- right here
}
```

Comment: why do I keep on forgetting the semi-colon..? ahahaha :D

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient (albeit a little complicated) way to do this will be with a ternary inside a PHP shorttag:

```
<td><span style="<?= $value['posted'] == 'posted' ? 'color: blue' : ($value['posted'] == 'cancel' ? 'color: red' : '') ?>">
    <?= $value['posted'] ?></span></td>
```

Comment: `if its "cancel" its red`?

Comment: No that was there from long ago :)

Comment: Yeah, so I fixed it... but it then requires a nested ternary.  Not a great option.