# IF statement in span style PHP

Tags: php, html, pdo, syntax

I'm trying to call a field of type int and display it on my website, but why when I enter the IF process into style span is not show?

this is code I'm trying to display a price field of type integer and display it with an icon

```
<a href="#"><i class=" fas fa-money-check-alt"></i>
     <span>
     (Rp.<?php if($count_balance->rowCount()>0) $count_balance->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>)
     </span>
     </a>
```

variable `$count_balance` is obtained from here

```
 $count_balance = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `balance` WHERE user_id = ?");
 $count_balance->execute([$user_id]);
```

so what I'm expecting is, the price appears from database like converting an integer to a string so that it can be displayed, but when I use `strval()` to convert it still doesn't work

Comment: `$count_balance.rowCount()` is incorrect and I would think would throw an error. Should be `$count_balance->rowCount()`. You also are doing nothing with the `style` attribute, what do comparison in that, or I'm missing something?

Comment: i followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936415/if-else-statement-span-style-php but when i replace `$count_balance->rowCount()` and put it without the `style` `span`, the value of price just doesn't show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of your code tests if row count is bigger then 0 and do nothing.

```
(Rp.<?php if($count_balance->rowCount()>0) $count_balance->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>)
```

You should echo/print the value as below:

```
(Rp.
<?php 
if($count_balance->rowCount()>0){
 $RpValue=$count_balance->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 echo $RpValue['your_desired_field'];
}
?>)
```

I recommend you to have a look on number_format() function also, it helps you to handle decimal houses/currency.